# Como diminuir a altura de table de Bootstrap?

Tags: tabela-html

Senhores,

Fiz uma tabela em bootstrap, mas quero diminuir a altura da linha, 
É possível alterar direto da table ou eu preciso ajustar no bootstrap.css?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered " >
      <thead>

        <tr style="background-color: #CEF6EC">
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nome Fornecedor</th>
          <th class="d-none d-sm-table-cell">Contato</th>
          <th class="d-none d-lg-table-cell">Telefone</th>
          <th width="100" class="text-center">Ações</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT id,nome,con,tel FROM cad_for WHERE del <> '1'";

        $sql = $pdo->query($sql);

        If($sql->rowCount()>0){
          foreach($sql->fetchAll() as $fornecedor){
            ?>

            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $fornecedor['id']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $fornecedor['nome']; ?></td>
              <td class="d-none d-sm-table-cell"><?php echo $fornecedor['con']; ?></td>
              <td class="d-none d-lg-table-cell"><?php echo $fornecedor['tel']; ?></td>

              <td>
                <a href="cad_for_vis.php?id=<?php echo $fornecedor['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Visualizar"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></a>
                <a href="cad_for_edi.php?id=<?php echo $fornecedor['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Editar cadastro"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-edit"></i></a>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <?php
          }
        }
        ?>

      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: se puder postar um trecho do código, ajuda na visualização do problema

Comment: Depende muito do CSS e HTML que tem nela. Pode ser que esses botões na última coluna estejam "mandando" na altura da linha. Teria quer ver o código.

Comment: Informar qual versão do Bootstrap estas usando também ajuda (é importante)

Comment: Sem a parte substancial do código, a versão do Bootstrap fica dificil alguém chegar ao entendimento...como dito no segundo comentário podem ser os botões. Se for para Bootstrap v4 podes usar a classe [**table-sm**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#small-table) que reduz o preenchimento pela metade

Comment: É feito em bootstrap 4.

Comment: Coloquei o código do tabela

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação vc deve usar a classe **`table-sm`** na sua tabela. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#small-table

> Add `.table-sm` to make tables more compact by cutting cell `padding` in half.

Em PT: Adicione `.table-sm` para tornar as tabelas mais compactas, reduzindo o `padding` de células pela metade.

Veja como fica no exemplo

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<table class="table table-sm table-striped table-hover table-bordered " >
<thead>

 <tr style="background-color: #CEF6EC">
 <th>ID</th>
 <th>Nome Fornecedor</th>
 <th class="d-none d-sm-table-cell">Contato</th>
 <th class="d-none d-lg-table-cell">Telefone</th>
 <th width="100" class="text-center">Ações</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

 <?php
 $sql = "SELECT id,nome,con,tel FROM cad_for WHERE del <> '1'";

 $sql = $pdo->query($sql);

 If($sql->rowCount()>0){
 foreach($sql->fetchAll() as $fornecedor){
  ?>

  <tr>
  <td><?php echo $fornecedor['id']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $fornecedor['nome']; ?></td>
  <td class="d-none d-sm-table-cell"><?php echo $fornecedor['con']; ?></td>
  <td class="d-none d-lg-table-cell"><?php echo $fornecedor['tel']; ?></td>

  <td>
   <a href="cad_for_vis.php?id=<?php echo $fornecedor['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Visualizar"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></a>
   <a href="cad_for_edi.php?id=<?php echo $fornecedor['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Editar cadastro"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-edit"></i></a>
  </td>
  </tr>

  <?php
 }
 }
 ?>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Isso mesmo, com a "table-sm" funcionou. Muito obrigado.

Comment: @Fábio que bom que deu certo ai, tmj

Answer (score -1):

A dica que vi acima é boa.
Uma boa prática, não altere direto o bootstrap.css, crie outro css que carrega após o bootstrap.css, nele, se alterar por exemplo: table tr { padding : 1px} isso vai fazer com que sobreponha a definição do arquivo carregado anteriormente.
Evita fazer muitas alterações, estude bem as classes bootstrap e use a mais adequada ou lista de classes para um elemento. Sobrepor definições em último caso e num arquivo geral.